# install4j how to create custom installer for macOS single bundle archive

Tags: macos, installation, install4j

To create installer for macOS (i4j 9.0.2) I used option "Installer-macOS single bundle". But it is deprecated now. As advised I use "Archive-macOS single bundle archive" instead. I want to have same installation dialogs as before. So, I selected "Use setup application" and had to create custom installer application in section "Installer". I created new application same as default "Installer" - manually added there all screens and actions with the same values as in "Installer".
Is this correct?
Anyway installation dialogs on Mac run without icons and images. Also installation wizard default location is not "Applications". What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> I created new application same as default "Installer" - manually added there all
> screens and actions with the same values as in "Installer". Is this correct?

You can put all the screens that you want to use in the macOS setup application into a screen group and then add a link to that screen group in the setup application. In that way you do not have to duplicate them.

> Anyway installation dialogs on Mac run without icons and images

I do not see that behavior here. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com with a download link to a media file that exhibits this behavior together with the .install4j project file.

> Also installation wizard default location is not "Applications".

The media file type is an archive, it does not have an installation directory, but the user drags the application bundle to the desired location. This is the default installation procedure on macOS. You can style the DMG so that it shows a symbolic link to /Applications as a target in the window. This makes it easier for the user. For more information on that topic, see

https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/concepts/dmgStyling.html